# Resolving of vptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, vptr

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void fn(){}
};

class der : public base {};
```

I know that compiler provides a member call VPTR in  class which is initialised with the exact VTABLE at run time by constructor. I have 2 questions

1) Which class holds the VPTR. or all the class is having seperate VPTR.

2) When executing statement `der d;`  how VPTR is being resolved at run time?

Answer (score 3):

`vtable` is created for the class that contains virtual function and for the classes derived from it.It means in your program `vtable` will be created for `base` class and `der` class.Each of these `vtables` would contain the address of virtual function `void fn()`.Now note that `der` class doesn't contain the definition of `void fn()`,hence its `vtable` contains the address of `base` class's `void fn()` function.Thus if u make a call like `d.fn();` the `void fn()` function of `base` class would get executed.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: a virtual table and a virtual pointer are implementation details, though all the C++ compilers I know use them, they are not mandated by the Standard, only the results are.*

To answer your specific question: each instance of a class with virtual methods (either its own, or inherited ones) or a class with (somewhere) a virtual inheritance relationship will need at least one virtual-pointer.

There can be several (when virtual inheritance or multi-inheritance are involved).

In *your* example, a single virtual pointer is sufficient. However it does not make sense to speak of it as being part of a `class`. The virtual pointer is part of the instance (object), and lives outsides the classes rules because those apply to the language, and the virtual pointer is an implementation mechanism.

Comment: Just to be clear: The vpointer is part of the instance, but the vtable is part of the class, right?

Comment: @Kerrek: typically yes. You may be able to share vtables if they're identical, or one is a pre- or suffix of the other.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) which class holds the VPTR. or all the class is having seperate VPTR.

Every `class` **object** has its own `vptr` if the `class` is polymorphic (i.e. contains `virtual` function or has `virtual` inheritance.) In this case both the classes has `virtual` function.

> 2) when executing statement **der d;** how VPTR is resolve at run time?

You are just declaring the object of `der`. But even if you call a function then in this case the call to any function is resolved at **compile time**. Virtual function resolution comes into picture only when the function is called with pointer/reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are telling class base is having a member vptr as well as class der is also having vptr.  so when object d is instantiated, constructor has to initialise the vptr with the vtable. both class will initialise vptr with thier respective VTALE.

Comment: Virtual inheritance means something else in C++ ... apparently you are using it as "inherits a virtual function".

Comment: @6502, In the case of `virtual` inheritance the object *may* contain `vptr`.

Comment: @iammilind: The C++ standard with polymorphic class means a class that defines or inherits virtual methods (see 10.3). This is unrelated to having a virtual base class.